# Where can I volunteer to become a QA Tester?

Tags: tester

I was hoping to find an open source project where I can be a volunteer QA Tester. Anyone know a project looking for one?

Comment: Have you tried to search for non profit organizations in your area/country?

Answer (score 10):

You can always Google open source software projects and contact the developers and show interest in volunteering for Testing. You can also try below links and also get help from various Software Testing forums.

[open testing Wikipedia mail list](http://chrismcmahonsblog.blogspot.in/2013/06/open-testing-wikipedia-mail-list-and.html)

[Weekend Testing](http://weekendtesting.com/)

[UTest](https://www.utest.com/)

[Mozilla Wiki QA/Execution/Web Testing/Contribute](https://wiki.mozilla.org/QA/Execution/Web_Testing/Volunteer)

Comment: Also Apache Software Foundation has many projects to contribute.

Answer (score 2):

Basically just about every live Open Source project welcomes everybody as a tester - the best ones to go for are those that you know something about the target use of the project. If you are a *potential or actual* member of their target audience your feedback will be much more to the point than if you are not.

1. List your interests to yourself in order of your level of interest/knowlege,
2. Search online for Open Source packages that are relevant to your top few interests
3. Find one, or more, that you like the look of
4. For each take a look at the trackers & newsgroups to get a feel for how welcoming of and responsive to feedback the developers are *it does differ between projects*
5. Read the **FAQ** and any other documentation.
6. Download both the current release for your platform(s).
7. Start testing it for yourself
8. Join the mailing list(s)
9. When you find a *potential* issue check the tracker to see if it is already reported, *if it is do you have some supplementary information to add?*, if it is not then raise a ticket.
10. Try not to "flood the system" one well written ticket on a serious point will be much more welcome than twenty trivial ones - also it is better to raise a ticket "Typos in Help" with a list of such rather than one for each.
11. Ideally also clone or fork the source code repository & build/test the "bleeding edge" code.
12. Patches are almost always welcome - even if they are to the documentation.

The **vast majority** of Open Source projects welcome constructive feedback, bug reports *please write them* ***politely*** with sufficient detail to be able to reproduce the problem, enhancement suggestions & tests on platforms that the developers may not have access to.

If you should get a poor response **from the developers** first consider the tone, language and detail of your ticket - did you sound demanding, unappreciative, etc., if you are reasonably sure that you have been polite, given enough detail, realistic in your expectations, etc. and you are still getting a poor response and feel that your efforts are not appreciated, *this is rare in my experience*, then maybe that isn't the project for you.

Above all never forget that the majority of Open Source Developers are also volunteers, usually unpaid, and have jobs & family as well.